# Polymorphism with Objectify

Tags: java, polymorphism, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am trying to use Objectify with a set of classes that inherit from an abstract base class:

```
class Container {
  @Id Long id;
  @Embedded Set<MyAbstract> children = new HashSet<MyAbstract>();
}

@Entity
abstract class MyAbstract { 
  @Id Long id;
}

@Subclass class Derived1 extends MyAbstract {}
@Subclass class Derived2 extends MyAbstract {}
```

Any idea how to code for this situation?
I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TypeUtils.newInstance(TypeUtils.java:321)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.load.EmbeddedMultivalueSetter.safeSet(EmbeddedMultivalueSetter.java:89)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.load.CollisionDetectingSetter.set(CollisionDetectingSetter.java:37)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.load(Transmog.java:326)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ConcreteEntityMetadata.toObject(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:212)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.QueryImpl$ToObjectIterator.translate(QueryImpl.java:611)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.QueryImpl$ToObjectIterator.translate(QueryImpl.java:1)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.TranslatingIterator.next(TranslatingIterator.java:35)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.QueryImpl.get(QueryImpl.java:368)
    at com.foodblox.server.model.ObjectifyTest.creation(ObjectifyTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TypeUtils.newInstance(TypeUtils.java:319)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit: This answer is obsolete. Polymorphism works for embedded classes in Objectify v5+]

The polymorphism that Objectify offers (as of 3.0beta2) lets you create polymorphic entities in a manner that is similar (but not identical) to JPA.  However, like JPA, this polymorphism does not extend to @Embedded classes.

It is not wholly unreasonable to request this behavior - file a feature request in the issue tracker.

Comment: filed! :)   http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine-spring/issues/detail?id=6

Answer (score 1):

Jeff just added polymorphism in to svn. It is going to be part of the 3.0 release of Ofy.

Comment: Yep, I assumed I had the relevant code (checked out the sources on March 10th). I saw some Polymorphism related tests, so I thought the feature was in.

Answer (score 0):

yours class, dont need a public constructor? Can you check that this is the case?

Comment: Java provides for a default no-args constructor.